# How apply function to all columns with specifis data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

I have big DataFrame with string and numeric columns. In string columns values have accents, I need convert them to "normal" letters. How can I apply a function to all specific type columns (in this case I need all string columns) in pandas DataFrame?

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(text):

    try:
        text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
    except NameError: # unicode is a default on python 3 
        pass

    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text)\
           .encode('ascii', 'ignore')\
           .decode("utf-8")
    return str(text)

import pandas as pd
data = [['Tóm','Čiž', 34], ['Ničk','Jóšš', 65], ['Julí', 'Álmó', 24]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'City', 'Age'])
```

I need output like: Tom, Ciz, Nick,...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

Firstly filter out columns:

```
col=df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']
```

Finally use `applymap()` method:

```
df[col]=df[col].applymap(strip_accents)
```

output of `df`:

```
    Name    City    Age
0   Tom     Ciz     34
1   Nick    Joss    65
2   Juli    Almo    24
```

Comment: [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) is another good option here: `df = df.select_dtypes('object').applymap(strip_accents)`